# Quickest way to find out if record exist

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have three functions which are all doing the same. I like to know whether `SELECT ... FROM EMP WHERE DEPT_ID = v_dept` returns any row.
Which one would be the fastest way?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RecordsFound1(v_dept IN EMP.DEPT_ID%TYPE) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
    n INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO res FROM EMP WHERE DEPT_ID = v_dept; 
    RETURN n > 0;
END;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RecordsFound2(v_dept IN EMP.DEPT_ID%TYPE) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
    CURSOR curEmp IS
    SELECT DEPT_ID FROM EMP WHERE DEPT_ID = v_dept; 
    dept EMP.DEPT_ID%TYPE;
    res BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
    OPEN curEmp;
    FETCH curEmp INTO dept; 
    res := curEmp%FOUND;
    CLOSE curEmp;
    RETURN res;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RecordsFound3(v_dept IN EMP.DEPT_ID%TYPE) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
    dept EMP.DEPT_ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT DEPT_ID INTO dept FROM EMP WHERE DEPT_ID = v_dept; 
    RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        RETURN FALSE;
    WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
        RETURN TRUE;
END;
/
```

Assume table `EMP` is very big and condition `WHERE DEPT_ID = v_dept` could match on thousands of rows.

Usually I would expect `RecordsFound2` to be the fastest, because it has to fetch (maximum) only one single row. So in terms of I/O it should be the best.

Comment: The fastest way probably uses the `EXISTS(...)` operator.

Comment: Why don't you test (on a db that has production-like amounts of data, of course!)? Call each function with the same parameter lots of times (eg. 1000 or 10000 times) and see how long it takes. Make sure you cover all the scenarios with each parameter call - 0 rows, 1 row, many rows, etc. That way, you'll have a suite of timings relevant to your database setup and data.

Comment: @wildplasser, I doubt, because for this `SELECT COUNT(*) fROM EMP WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM EMP WHERE DEPT_ID = v_dept)` the table has to be queried twice.

Comment: @Boneist, by this you would mainly test the performance of your cache but you don't compare the logic.

Comment: How about `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DUAL WHERE EXISTS ( select 'x' from EMP WHERE DEPT_ID = v_dept)`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "don't compare the logic"? Sure, after the first pass-through the data will be in the cache, but by running each function many times, you're comparing like-for-like.

Comment: Or a simple `SELECT 1 INTO res WHERE EXISTS ( select * from EMP WHERE DEPT_ID = v_dept)`?

Comment: What exactly will you be using this function for? Because as Marmite Bomber suggests in their answer, not calling it would be faster. In most cases it would be better to do whatever it is you're doing and then check if any rows were processed or not as part of that, rather than having a separate check.

Comment: `RecordsFound3` is likely to fail anyway.

Comment: @mustaccio, why do you think so?

Comment: Because, as you say, _"condition `WHERE DEPT_ID = v_dept` could match on thousands of rows"_, all of which you are trying to assign to a variable.

Comment: @mustaccio, that is covered by `WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN RETURN TRUE;`

Answer (score 2):

For the non-believers: the exists() version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RecordsFound0(v_dept IN EMP.DEPT_ID%TYPE) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
BEGIN
    RETURN EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM EMP WHERE DEPT_ID = v_dept);
END;
```

---

The Postgresql version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RecordsFound0(v_dept IN EMP.DEPT_ID%TYPE) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$func$
BEGIN
    RETURN EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM EMP WHERE DEPT_ID = v_dept);
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

And in Postgres the function can be implemented in pure sql, without the need for plpgsql(in Postgres the select does not need a `... FROM DUAL`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RecordsFound0s(v_debt IN EMP.DEPT_ID%TYPE) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$func$
    SELECT EXISTS( SELECT NULL FROM EMP WHERE DEPT_ID = v_debt);
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

---

---

Note: the *unary* `EXISTS(...)` operator yields a Boolean, which is exactly what you want.

---

Note2: I hope I have the Oracle syntax correct. (keywords RETURN <-->RETURNS and AS <-->IS)

Comment: For sure the shortest version. But do you think it is also the fastest, i.e. does Oracle immediately return the result when first record is found?

Comment: Of course it is the fastest. And of course the engine will stop counting when the count reaches one. EXISTS existed before LEFT JOIN, and has always been the workhorse inside JOINS and ANTI-JOINS.

Comment: EXISTS is no PL/SQL word. For this reason I get the error `"PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'EXISTS' may be used inside a SQL statement only"` in Oracle 11g. I agree though, that EXISTS is most likely the fastest method. Only it looks more clumsy in PL/SQL for you must select from DUAL and Oracle SQL doesn't know BOOLEAN.

Comment: I agree to Thorsten Kettner, the "exists" just works within SQL not PL/SQL. So this is not a solution.

Comment: In that case, you could wrap a `SELECT ... FROM DUAL` around it, I guess? (wrapping a function around an operator is a silly idea anyway) BTW: the question was tagged SQL, not PLSQL.

Answer (score 1):

**Your solution 1 Count all occurrences:**

You have the DBMS do much more work than needed. why let it scan the table and count all occurences when you only want to know whether at least one exists or not? This is slow. (But on a small emp table with an index on dept_id this may still look fast :-)

**Your solution 2 Open a Cursor and only fetch the first record**

A good idea and probably rather fast, as you stop, once you found a record. However, the DBMS doesn't know that you only want to look for the mere existence and may decide for a slow execution plan, as it expects you to fetch all matches.

**Your solution 3 Fetch the one record or get an exception**

This may be a tad faster, as the DBMS expects to find one record only. However, it must test for further matches in order to raise TOO_MANY_ROWS in case. So in spite of having found a record already it must look on.

**solution 4 Use COUNT and ROWNUM**

By adding `AND ROWNUM = 1` you show the DBMS that you want one record only. At a minimum the DBMS knows it can stop at some point, at best it even notices that it is only one record needed. So depending on the implementation the DBMS *may* find the optimal execution plan.

**solution 5 Use EXISTS**

EXISTS is made to check for mere existence, so the DBMS can find the optimal execution plan. EXISTS is an SQL word, not a PL/SQL word and the SQL engine doesn't know BOOLEAN, so the function gets a bit clumsy:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RecordsFound1(v_dept IN EMP.DEPT_ID%TYPE) RETURN BOOLEAN IS
  v_1_is_yes_0_is_no INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_1_is_yes_0_is_no
    FROM DUAL
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE DEPT_ID = v_dept); 

    RETURN n = 1;
END;
```

Comment: So maybe `AND ROWNUM = 1` should be added everywhere.

Comment: @Wernfried: As mentioned, I don't know whether the DBMS makes different plans for `ROWNUM = 1`, `ROWNUM < 2` and `ROWNUM < 2000`. It is better than to simply count all rows when you only want to know whether zero or more. And yes, it may help in the second and third solution, that's right. But it is still not guaranteed to get the best execution plan.

Comment: `and PL/SQL doesn't know BOOLEAN` Huh? How can the function return boolean if the language does not understand boolean?

Comment: @wildplasser: That was a careless mistake; it is Oracle SQL which doesn't know BOOLEAN.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute fastest ways is to not call the count function at all.

A typical pattern is

```
count the number of rows
if cnt = 0 then do something
else read chunk of data and process
```

Simple read the data and than perform the count test on it.

Comment: In general yes, but this is not my question. Maybe I don't need any data from table EMP at all, I just like to know if any record is found.

Answer (score 0):

you can break a SQL by adding an extra condition to your where-clause:

where ...
and rownum = 1;

this stops immediatly if at least one record is found and it is as fast as the "exists" operator.

See the followint sample code:

```
create or replace function test_record_exists(pi_some_parameter in varchar2) return boolean is
  l_dummy varchar2(10);
begin
  select 'x' 
    into l_dummy
    from <your table>
    where <column where you want to filter for> = pi_some_parameter
      and rownum = 1;

  return (true);

  exception
    when no_data_found then
      return (false);

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

```
select count(*)
from   my_table
where  ...
  and  rownum = 1;
```

... then the query will:

- be executed in the most efficient fashion
- always return a single row
- return either 0 or 1

This three factors make it very fast and very easy to use in PL/SQL as you do not have to concern yourself with whether a row is returned or not.

The returned value is also amenable to use as a true/false boolean, of course.

If you wanted to list the departments that either do or do not have any records in the emp table then I would certainly use EXISTS, as the semi-(anti)join is the most efficient means of executing the query:

```
select *
from   dept
where  [NOT] exists (
       select null
       from   emp
       where  emp.dept_id = dept.id);
```